# Search a sharepoint 2007 site from a sharepoint 2010 instance

Tags: 2010, 2007, search, search-scope

We are in the process of migrating some remaining content to our sharepoint 2010 instance, in the meantime we wanted to set up our 2010 search so that it had the capability to search our entire 2007 instance as well.

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, can someone point me in the right direction.

Ideally we would like to be able to define this as a scope in our 2010 environment with the additional option to have it included in the "all sites" scope. However if there are other methods I welcome the suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is remarkably simple to do.  Go into Search Administration in your 2010 farm and create a new content source, enter the URL to your 2007 farm and give it a crawl schedule.  You will need to make sure that the account used for the crawl in 2010 has full read permission to the 2007 content via Web Application Policy in the 2007 farm.  After that, the 2007 content should appear in the 2010 search results as soon as the crawl completes.

Per [this note](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262926%28v=office.14%29.aspx), if your 2007 farm has multiple site collections on the same web application then you need to enter the root url to each site collection in your newly defined content source for 2007 sites.

Comment: To build on Daves answer, in 2010 you can then specify a Scope for the 2007 Content Source, very very easy to do.